# EOSIO - cleos wallet create command throwing error "Invalid content-length response"

Tags: eos

As per the [EOSIO Docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/learn-about-wallets-keys-and-accounts-with-cleos), I ran the `cleos wallet create` command to create my first `default` wallet. However it is throwing following error.

`3401237ms thread-0   main.cpp:2756                 main                 ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10)
response_content_length >= 0: Invalid content-length response`

Answer (score 0):

After going through [few](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4637) [github](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4594) issues, I figured out that following change to `config.ini` will fix this error.

Config File Location: `/tmp/eosio/config`, and File: `config.ini`, and the property `http-validate-host` should be changed from `1` (true) to `0` (false), as shown below:

`http-validate-host=0`